# Understanding the implementation of memcpy()

Tags: c, memcpy, language-implementation

I was looking the implementation of memcpy.c, I found a different memcpy code. I couldnt understand why do they do (((ADDRESS) s) | ((ADDRESS) d) | c) & (sizeof(UINT) - 1)

```
#if !defined(__MACHDEP_MEMFUNC)

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma function(memcpy)
#undef __MEMFUNC_ARE_INLINED
#endif

#if !defined(__MEMFUNC_ARE_INLINED)
/* Copy C bytes from S to D.
 * Only works if non-overlapping, or if D < S.
 */
EXTERN_C void * __cdecl memcpy(void *d, const void *s, size_t c)
{
    if ((((ADDRESS) s) | ((ADDRESS) d) | c) & (sizeof(UINT) - 1)) {

        BYTE *pS = (BYTE *) s;
        BYTE *pD = (BYTE *) d;
        BYTE *pE = (BYTE *) (((ADDRESS) s) + c);

        while (pS != pE)
            *(pD++) = *(pS++);
    }
    else {
        UINT *pS = (UINT *) s;
        UINT *pD = (UINT *) d;
        UINT *pE = (UINT *) (BYTE *) (((ADDRESS) s) + c);

        while (pS != pE)
            *(pD++) = *(pS++);
    }
    return d;
}

#endif /* ! __MEMFUNC_ARE_INLINED */
#endif /* ! __MACHDEP_MEMFUNC */
```

Comment: And that's why you don't want to write `memcpy` yourself :-) The real beauty is only visible when you look at the generated machine code, though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The code is testing whether the addresses are aligned suitably for a `UINT`. If so, the code copies using `UINT` objects. If not, the code copies using `BYTE` objects.

The test works by first performing a bitwise OR of the two addresses. Any bit that is on in either address will be on in the result. Then the test performs a bitwise AND with `sizeof(UINT) - 1`. It is expected the the size of a `UINT` is some power of two. Then the size minus one has all lower bits on. E.g., if the size is 4 or 8, then one less than that is, in binary 11<sub>2</sub> or 111<sub>2</sub>. If either address is not a multiple of the size of a `UINT`, then it will have one of these bits on, and the test will indicate it. (Usually, the best alignment for an integer object is the same as its size. This is not necessarily true. A modern implementation of this code should use `_Alignof(UINT) - 1` instead of the size.)

Copying with `UINT` objects is faster, because, at the hardware level, one load or store instruction loads or stores all the bytes of a `UINT` (likely four bytes). Processors will typically copy faster when using these instructions than when using four times as many single-byte load or store instructions.

This code is of course implementation dependent; it requires support from the C implementation that is not part of the base C standard, and it depends on specific features of the processor it executes on.

A more advanced `memcpy` implementation could contain additional features, such as:

- If one of the addresses is aligned but the other is not, use special load-unaligned instructions to load multiple bytes from one address, with regular store instructions to the other address.
- If the processor has Single Instruction Multiple Data instructions, use those instructions to load or store many bytes (often 16, possibly more) in a single instruction.

Answer (score 14):

The code

```
((((ADDRESS) s) | ((ADDRESS) d) | c) & (sizeof(UINT) - 1))
```

Checks to see if either `s`, `d`, or `c` are not aligned to the size of a `UINT`.

For example, if `s = 0x7ff30b14`, `d = 0x7ffa81d8`, c = `256`, and `sizeof(UINT) == 4`, then:

```
s         = 0b1111111111100110000101100010100
d         = 0b1111111111110101000000111011000
c         = 0b0000000000000000000000100000000
s | d | c = 0b1111111111110111000101111011100
(s | d | c) & 3 =                        0b00
```

So both pointers are aligned.  It is easier to copy memory between pointers that are *both* aligned, and this does it with only one branch.

On many architectures, `*(UINT *) ptr` is *much* faster if `ptr` is correctly aligned to the width of a `UINT`.  On some architectures, `*(UINT *) ptr` will actually crash if `ptr` is not correctly aligned.

Comment: It checks the length, too.

Comment: Wow, talk about conciseness over clarity. Any code that requires four sets of parens ought to be rethought.

Comment: @EricAndres Welcome to the world of performance. That kind of stuff is all over the place. :)

Comment: @Mysticial I'm sure it is. I'm not a C programmer, so I tend to dismiss things like this pretty easily. This definitely is a piece of code where the micro-optimization can be justified.

Comment: @EricAndres But the parentheses aren't what matters, of course.  Ideally, you'd see `((ADDRESS) s)` and `((ADDRESS) d)` as opaque chunks `S` and `D`, so you've got `(S | D | c) & (sizeof(UNIT) - 1)`, which isn't _too_ bad, and then you've got one more set from the `if ( … ) …`.  The expression itself isn't nested in a particularly complex way.